# Firebase ResetPassword issue

Tags: firebase

I am building user authentication in my website using Angular and Firebase's Email & Password authentication framework. This is NOT using the Firebase Simple Login Framework but the newly introduced native framework.

My code links to Firebase using:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

I can create users, login and so on but the ResetPassword call fails with the following error.

```
Error: Firebase.resetPassword failed: First argument must be a valid object.
    at Error (native)
    at E (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.0/firebase.js:15:73)
    at F.G.td (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.0/firebase.js:192:79)
    at Object.resetPassword (http://localhost:8000/src/js/services/loginservice.js:78:27)
    at k.$scope.resetPassword (http://localhost:8000/src/js/controllers.js:35:20)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:177:68
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:171:237
    at f (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:194:174)
    at k.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:68)
    at k.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:346)
```

The code I use is from the firebase example as follows:

```
ref.resetPassword(email, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("Password reset email sent successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("Error sending password reset email:", error);
  }
});
```

I have verified that a valid email id is being passed in.

Can you please let me know what the issue is?

Thanks in advance
vm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the firebase documentation, you should be passing in an object not a string.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/resetPassword.html

```
var credentials = {email: email};
ref.resetPassword(credentials, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("Password reset email sent successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("Error sending password reset email:", error);
  }
}
```

Comment: The API documentation and their 'guide' differ.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Please contact them directly to let them know of the discrepancy. You'll be doing them a favor and anybody else who might get stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using an object no longer works, it would keep giving me "First argument must contain the key "email", even then the object was as the answer above. 
After much frustration i got it working passing the email parameter as per the firebase docs.

```
$scope.resetPassword = function(email){
          console.log("made in to auth method for reset passowrd with email - " + email);

ref.resetPassword({
    email: email
}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "INVALID_USER":
        console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error resetting password:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Password reset email sent successfully!");
  }
});

}
```